# Каким образом опубликовать интернет-магазин с BD, в качестве примера работы?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Проблема в том что сайт создавался с целью опробывать технологию с дальнейшим включением в порфолио, так чтобы переходя по ссылке открывался рабочий магазин, с возможностью просмотра кода, как на git pages?

Comment: Разместите код на Github, сайт - на хостинге?

Comment: Так и сделал, спасибо